# My first recursive function not calling itself correctly?

Tags: php, arrays

This piece of code is supposed to find the highest value of a group, no matter how many nested arrays there are.  I am trying, for the first time, to create a function that will call itself every time the event happens, that's the value is an array. Why is it saying my variables are not defined?

```
<?php
    $arr = array("1", "2", array("3", "4"));

    function getitMax($arr){
        foreach ($arr as $value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                getitMax($value);
            } else {
                $max_array=array($value);
            }
        }
    }
    getitMax($arr);

    echo max($max_array);
?>
```

Comment: You haven't posted any code.

Comment: 4 seconds ahead of me :)

Comment: in function you ve to return something, and u ve to store data somewhere while calling function. I think so. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're just calling your function here:

```
if(is_array($value)){
        getitMax($value);

}
```

-but doing nothing with it's result. And also your function has no `return` - i.e. result will be `null`. To fix this, do something like:

```
function  getitMax($arr)
{
    $max = null;
    foreach($arr as $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            $current = getitMax($value);
        }
        else 
        {
            $current = $value;
        }
        //assign max to current if current is larger:
        if($current>$max)
        {
           $max = $current;
        }
    }
    return $max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code might be a bit lengthy approach:

```
<?php   
class GetMax {
    private $max_array = '';
    public function getitMax($arr){     
        foreach ($arr as $value){
            if(is_array($value)){
                $this->getitMax($value);
            } else {
                $this->max_array[] = $value;
            }
        }       
        return max($this->max_array);
    }
}

$m = new GetMax();
$arr = array("1", "2", array("3", "4"));
echo $m->getitMax($arr);
?>
```